# Cannot use ssd.pytorch package in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use this package [ssd.pytorch](https://github.com/amdegroot/ssd.pytorch) in google colab but it is not working. I have added image of the code in the last line of the post. Here's my code-

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import cv2 
!git clone https://github.com/amdegroot/ssd.pytorch.git #cloning the package in colab first
!pip install -q BaseTransform
from data import BaseTransform, VOC_CLASSES as labelmap
```

whenever I try to install BaseTransform this message shows up.

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement BaseTransform (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for BaseTransform

So I can't import anything. Should I install what I cloned first? But when I try to install ssd.pytorch the same message shows up.

```
!pip install -q ssd.pytorch
```

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ssd.pytorch (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for ssd.pytorch

As I am importing from the folder data should I install using that folder name?

```
!pip install -q data
```

For some reason this works and I don't know why. But still can't import anything when I use this line.

```
from data import BaseTransform, VOC_CLASSES as labelmap
```

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 from data import BaseTransform, VOC_CLASSES as labelmap. ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseTransform'
>
> NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
>   manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt. To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
>   "Open Examples" button below.

What should I do to import the package properly? 
This is what the code looks like in colab:
[image: This is what the code looks like in colab]

Answer (score 0):

the problem you got, is because you haven't change directory before import package.

just run the code below before you import

`import os`

`os.chdir('ssd.pytorch')`

besides, BaseTransform is a class defined in ssd.pytorch/data. You cannot install it.